# Time complexity of loop multiplying the value by two or three

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I found the below for-loop in an SO question.

I found that the time complexity is `O(n log n)`.

How would I find the time complexity if we change `k *= 2` to `k *= 3`?

```
// 'int n' is defined somewhere
int var = 0;
for (int k = 1; k <= n; k *= 2)
   for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
      var++;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The time complexity would still be `O(n log n)`.

For `k *= 2`, the `log` would be base 2.

For `k *= 3`, the `log` would be base 3.

But change in the base of `log` only affects the result by a constant factor (this can be derived from the fact that `logba` = `logca / logcb`, for any base `c`), which is ignored in big-O notation, thus they have the same time complexity.

---

Where do we get `log2n` from anyway?

Well, the values of `k` goes like this:

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., 2m  for some m, where 2m <= n < 2m+1
= 20 + 21 + 22 + ... + 2m
```

And of course there are just `m+1` (`0` to `m`) terms above, so the loop runs `m+1` times.

Now if we can use some basic logarithms to get `m` in terms of `n`:

```
2m = c.n   for some constant c, where 1 <= c < 2
log22m = log2(c.n)
m log22 = log2(c.n)
m.1 = log2c + log2n
m = O(log2c + log2n)
  = O(log2n)               // constant terms can be ignored
```

We can also follow the exact same approach as above for `k *= 3` by just replacing `2` by `3`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is N×log<sub>3</sub>N.

To see why, you need to figure out why the answer to the original problem is N×log<sub>2</sub>N. How many times (let's call it `k`) will it execute? It will execute as many times as needed to multiply `2` by itself so that the result would exceed `N`. In other words, 2<sup>k</sup> > N. Now apply logarithm to both sides of the expression (the definition of logarithm can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm)) to see that `k` > log<sub>2</sub>N.

The reason that we used `2` as the base of the logarithm is that the base of the exponent on the left was `2`. It is easy to see that if the base of exponen is `3`, applying log<sub>3</sub> yields the answer to the problem that you are solving.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed formally and methodically using Sigma notation:

[image]

Check the last slides of this [document](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt).